# strcmp() not working as expected

Tags: php, strcmp

```
echo($menuVal['icon']);
/* if($menuVal['icon'] !== 'fa-dashboard' ){
$menuHTML .= '<span class="ico fa fa-fw fa-chevron-right"></span>';
}*/
$cont=strcmp($menuVal["icon"],"fa-dashboard");
echo($cont);
if((strcmp($menuVal["icon"],"fa-dashboard")) != 0 ){
    $menuHTML .= '<span class="ico fa fa-fw fa-chevron-right"></span>';
}
```

in this code i'm trying to print the icon using php if it value is not equal to fa-dashboard,i think `strcmp` will produce an output zero if inputs are equal,but in this code strcmp is producing an output of 243 when both strings are equal and the `if` condition is worked when put 243 instead of 0.

i added the output obtained on below,i'm also checked the value of `$menuVal['icon']` to check what it prints,

```
fa-dashboard 243fa-globe 768fa-puzzle-piece 3072fa-pie-chart
3072fa-gears 768fa-anchor -768
```

is there any error in this code?how can i fix that?
any help will get appreciated..........!!!

Comment: the first iteration should not satisfy the condition (its `fa-dashboard` as shown in your output), all other icon values should, so whats the problem?

Comment: @ghost yes that is my problem,first iteration

Comment: is there any error in my strcmp() function?

Comment: no one can reproduce that on our end, we can make assumptions based on that output example that you have. the first iteration should yield zero

Comment: ok  i will add the complete code

Comment: but it's very huge

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checking if the entire string equals fa-dashboard which is not.

If fa-dashboard is always the first item you can use strncmp to match only the first n characters.

```
int strncmp ( string $str1 , string $str2 , int $len )
```

> This function is similar to strcmp(), with the difference that you can specify the (upper limit of the) number of characters from each string to be used in the comparison.